# Find parameters given midpoints

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Given that point $D$ is the midpoint of $L$ and $J$ and $P$ is the midpoint of $F$ and $D$, and $\vec{OP} = z_1\vec{OL}+z_2\vec{OF}+z_3\vec{OJ}$, what are the values of $z_1, z_2, z_3$?

---

I'm very confused on how to approach this problem. So, I think that
$\vec{OL} = 2\vec{OD}$, and $\vec{OF}=2*\vec{OP}$, but I'm not sure how to proceed (if this is correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"$D$ is the midpoint of $L$ and $J$" is equivalent to
$$\vec{OD}=\frac12(\vec{OL}+\vec{OJ})$$
Likewise, "$P$ is the midpoint of $F$ and $D$" becomes
$$\vec{OP}=\frac12(\vec{OF}+\vec{OD})$$
Substitute:
$$\vec{OP}=\frac12\left(\vec{OF}+\frac12(\vec{OL}+\vec{OJ})\right)=\frac12\vec{OF}+\frac14\vec{OL}+\frac14\vec{OJ}$$
and so $z_1,z_2,z_3=\frac14,\frac12,\frac14$ respectively.

Comment: I think I was misunderstanding what the O meant, could you explain what O means, in this context?

Comment: @nodel The origin of whatever coordinate system we are using. Almost always Cartesian.

Answer (score 0):

$\vec{OD} = (\vec{OL} + \vec{OJ})/2$ and $\vec{OP} = (\vec{OF} +\vec{OD})/2$

Now substituting the $\vec{OD}$ :-

$\vec{OP} =\vec{OL}/4 + \vec{OF}/2 + \vec{OJ}/4 $

$z_1=1/4$

$z_2=1/2$

$z_3=1/4$